# dygraphs fillGraph solid

Tags: transparency, dygraphs

I am using dygraphs, and I was wondering if I could turn off the transparency of the fill graph so that I get a solid color instead of the fillGraph with a bit of transparency. If so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can set "fillAlpha: 1.0" to get an opaque fill. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/55/

and

http://dygraphs.com/options.html#fillAlpha